# How to keep both data on aws s3 and glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, data-migration, amazon-glacier, s3fs

I want to keep a backup of an AWS s3 bucket. If I use Glacier, it will archive the files from the bucket and moved to the Glacier but it will also delete the files from s3. I don't want to delete the files from s3. One option is to try with EBS volume. You can mount the AWS s3 bucket with s3fs and copy it to the EBS volume. Another way is do an rsync of the existing bucket to a new bucket which will act as a clone. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is cross-region replication:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/

setup versioning and setup the replication.
on the target bucket you could setup a policy to archive to Glacier (or you could just use the bucket as a backup as is).

(this will only work between 2 regions, i.e. buckets cannot be in the same region)

Comment: S3 now supports same zone replication: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/amazon-s3-introduces-same-region-replication/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your data to be present in both primary and backup locations then this is more of a data replication use case.

Consider using [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html) which is an event driven compute service.
You can write a simple piece of code to copy the data wherever you want. This will execute every time there is a change in S3 bucket. 
For more info check the [official documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/lambda/).